# RoR 3.2.5 Railscasts #102: Autocomplete: Form is prepopulated with data (should be blank)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, jquery-autocomplete

I'm going off Railscasts 102.

My current issue is that my search form is already populated with data when the page loads.

I have one model, listing, and 5 columns on that model: website, url, comments, doctor, and date. In this case I am just worrying about website.

My listings.js.coffee is

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
    source: $('#search').data('autocomplete-source')
```

And my index.html.erb file (the important part) is

```
<%= form_tag '/listings', :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, data: {autocomplete_source: Listing.order(:website).map(&:website)} %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', :class => 'echo-search-tag', :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

When I load the page, the search form is already populated with

**{:data=>{:autocomplete_source=>["Doctors4US", "How To Get Better", "Rafael's Epic Doctor Site", "Testing Admin", "WebMD"]}}**

Obviously this shouldn't be the case. The JS console is giving me an error of:

*Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object # is not a function*

I saw another Stack Overflow post in regards to this, I tried that solution but it didn't make a difference.

Note: when I tried test data for the source in listings.js.coffee, like ['foo', 'fore', 'food'], the autocomplete was working correctly.

Also note that the search function is working correctly aside from autocomplete.

Any input is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you created a json output file in your listing controller? Can you post your listing controller code?

Comment: Hi Robert, yes I can post it. Gist here: https://gist.github.com/3871885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the issue was that the text_field_tag takes 2 arguments, and that is why the search form was being prepopulated with the data.

So I just added nil for the 2nd argument

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, nil, data: {autocomplete_source: Listing.order(:website).map(&:website)} %>
```

And voila! Working.

Now trying to figure out how to add multiple columns to Listing.order and .map (ie, having not only :website, but :comments, :doctor, and :url). Input appreciated!

Comment: `<%= text_field_tag :search, nil, data: {autocomplete_source: Listing.all.map {|listing| [listing.comments, listing.doctor, listing.url, listing.website] }.flatten.sort }`